# What does "You get this endless downward ratchet" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What does "You get this endless downward ratchet" mean here? Does it mean "we always get downward progression"? This is from a [fortune.com article](https://fortune.com/2021/04/12/taxing-wealthy-pay-for-covid-recovery-bad-idea-nobel-prize-winning-economist/)

> “In economic booms, it always picks up, but it never picks up as far as the previous peak,” Deaton said. “**You get this endless downward ratchet**. That’s something we really need to turn around, and it’s going to be hard.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but there's more to it than that. A ratchet is a physical tool that prevents motion in one direction (usually down); a downward ratchet prevents motion upwards, and as the quote says, doing this (taxing the so-called rich for the latest government scheme) creates a series of upper limits, like an upside-down mountain range -- the employment rate may fall, but it never rises past the point of the previous time it was ratcheted.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=ratchet